Set border to table header
I am working on a table that can have no headers, the first row as a header, the first column as a header, or both the first column and the first row as headers.
The expected output is that the headers should have a border on the right, except when the first row is set as the header
Expected output

But the current output is

The issue is that I am getting a border-right even when the first row is set as the header. Is there a solution to avoid this?


table {
  border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  th {
    padding: 16px;
    border-right: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
    background: #F1F1F1
  }
  td {
    padding: 16px;
  }
  tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
  }
  tr:first-child th:not(:first-child) {
    border-right: 0;
  }
}
<p> Table with first row as header</p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Fruits</th>
      <th>Veggies</th>
      <th>Junks</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Carrot</td>
      <td>Burger</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Betroot</td>
      <td>Fries</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p> Table with first column as header</p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Fruits</th>
      <td>Veggies</td>
      <td>Junks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Apple</th>
      <td>Carrot</td>
      <td>Burger</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Orange</th>
      <td>Betroot</td>
      <td>Fries</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p> Table with first row and column as header</p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Fruits</th>
      <th>Veggies</th>
      <th>Junks</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Apple</th>
      <td>Carrot</td>
      <td>Burger</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Orange</th>
      <td>Betroot</td>
      <td>Fries</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>Table with no header</p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Fruits</td>
      <td>Veggies</td>
      <td>Junks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Carrot</td>
      <td>Burger</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Betroot</td>
      <td>Fries</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



codepen
NOTE : I don't have access to add/modify the HTML or add JS. Also the order of the tables here are just for example, it changes based on the requirement

@mplungjantr:first-child th {    border-right: 0;  } removes the border even when first row and first column is set as header

The border-right is removed for all headers in the first row except the first column (using :not(:first-child)).
A specific rule ensures that the first column headers (th:first-child) always retain their border-right style, even when it's part of a table that also has the first row as a header
<style>
  table {
    border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }
  th, td {
    padding: 16px;
    border-right: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
  }
  th {
    background: #F1F1F1;
  }
  /* Disable right border for headers in the first row */
  tr:first-child th:not(:first-child) {
    border-right: 0;
  }
  /* Always add border-right for first column headers */
  tr th:first-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
  }
  /* Set borders for table rows except headers */
  tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
</style>


This is not adding border-right to the first header when table has either first column as header or both first column and row as header

You can fix this using CSS.
I have added &:nth-of-type(1) tr:first-child th { border-right: 0; }
nth-of-type(1) - Select only first Table
tr:first-child - Select first header row of first Table
For more info you can check MDN documentation
Link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type
Updated Code is below.


table{
      border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      th{
         padding: 16px;
         border-right: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
         background: #F1F1F1 
      }
      td{
         padding: 16px;
      }

      tr{
         border-bottom: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
      }
      tr:first-child th:not(:first-child){
         border-right: 0;
      }
      &:nth-of-type(1) tr:first-child th {
         border-right: 0;
      }
   }
<p> Table with first row as header<p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Fruits</th>
      <th>Veggies</th>
      <th>Junks</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Carrot</td>
      <td>Burger</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Betroot</td>
      <td>Fries</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p> Table with first column as header<p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Fruits</th>
      <td>Veggies</td>
      <td>Junks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Apple</th>
      <td>Carrot</td>
      <td>Burger</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Orange</th>
      <td>Betroot</td>
      <td>Fries</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p> Table with first row and column as header<p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Fruits</th>
      <th>Veggies</th>
      <th>Junks</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Apple</th>
      <td>Carrot</td>
      <td>Burger</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Orange</th>
      <td>Betroot</td>
      <td>Fries</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p> Table with no header<p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Fruits</td>
      <td>Veggies</td>
      <td>Junks</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Carrot</td>
      <td>Burger</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Betroot</td>
      <td>Fries</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




The order of the table might vary. It is not always that the first table will have first row as header

In order changing case use CSS class or ID to the table element & based on it change css @user3699344

yeah that is right but I don't have access to modify/add HTML and add any JS
